# Limit of $(1+5/n+6/n^2)^n$ when $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Find $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{5}{n}+\frac{6}{n^2}\right)^n$$

Comment: I am not sure..

Comment: You're not sure if you've tried anything?  It's Schroedinger's mathematician! What would you say happens if you just ignore that $6/n^2$ term entirely?  Just look at $(1+5/6)^n$.

Comment: will that go to infinity I was actually thinking (1+k/n)^n goes to e^k...so I am not so sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this factors as $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^n=e^2\cdot e^3=e^5$$
Interestingly, this is the same answer as we would have had without the $\frac{6}{n^2}$, so this term is insignificant in a sense.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** (1 + 5/6 + 6/n^2) > (1 + 5/6) = 11 / 6 > 1. Then now, you raise a number which is greater than than 1 to larger and larger powers, then ... Can you continue with this ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just changed my question to (1+5/n+6/n^2)^n

Comment: @afsd dfsaf. For sure, the problem is quite different !